# avoid browser reset from onclick event (prototype)

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs

I have few anchors with a click event:

```
$$('.someanchor').invoke('observe', 'click', somefunction );
```

When the anchor is clicked, the browser scrolls to top.
I tried to insert `return false` at the end of `somefunction`, but it still scrolls up.

Usually I would use something like:

```
Event.observe('somelement', 'click', somefunction, false);
```

But this doesnt work for a collection of elements. So how do I `return false` from a `invoke` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `somefunction`, add the following at the end of the function body (make sure `e` is the last argument, and is used for the `Event` object):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

"e.preventDefault()" prevents the anchor default behavior but not the event propagation (bubbling). I would use "Event.stop(event)" to neutralize both, just for being on the safe side.